Will unplugging power to outside AC unit cause a fuse to blow in the fiurnace?
I accidentally cause the power plugs on AC unit outside to come unplugged.
I called out a Pro and he plugged back in.
He confirmed power is going from basement furnace to Nest thermostat, but no power from Nest coming back down?
Nest shows error message that HVAC not connected?
I've tried to research it, and it looks like maybe the purple fuse that goes to the red wire might have blown?
I'm a lady with no repair experience.
The Pro said it's the thermostat.
Any suggestions? Should I take off  scary access panel and mess with the fuses?
I know where the light switch is to turn off the power to the unit.

Is this "scary access panel" in the furnace housing or are you taking about the breaker panel? If the latter, I do not think it would be safe for you to remove the front of the panel. If the scary access panel is inside the furnce, you can use the switch to disconnect the 120 V AC hot phase and then remove the cover to expose the fuse. Do you have something to test the fuse or would you just visually determie if it is blown?

It is not legal to have an outside A/C condenser on cord-and-plug. It's required to be hardwired, and the hardwired connection needs to be sufficiently sturdy as to resist damage.
